# PHP Ratchet periodic sending of messages to the client

Tags: php, timer, websocket, ratchet

I need to periodically send a message to the client. To set the timer, I use the following code:

```
$loop = Factory::create();
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function() {
    echo "timer";
});
```

but how can I push a message from the timer to the client?
Unfortunately, neither Google nor the documentation for the Ratchet did not help me.

Comment: The same way you push any message `$client->send($msg);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I tried this before written on the stackoverflow and I receive an error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function send() on a non-object

Comment: @tovog a bit late but I just got the answer for this today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412951/periodically-sending-mesages-to-clients-in-ratchet#38413175